# FailedToDecompressContent reading from file uploaded with gsutil -Z

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Google Dataflow pipeline that is reading a text file that I uploaded with `gsutil cp -Z`, in other words in gzipped format.

When I try to run the pipeline (job ID `2018-03-21_01_28_54-102058310819679700`) I get the following error:

```
FailedToDecompressContent: Content purported to be compressed with gzip but failed to decompress.
at HandleExceptionsAndRebuildHttpConnections (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py:304)
```

I can download the file fine using `gsutil cp` to copy it back to my local machine.

I'm using `ReadFromText` without any particular options.

If I replace the file with an uncompressed version, it works, though the file is five times as large.

Is it possible to get reading from compressed files to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to read directly from compressed files. I have done so with `TextIO.Read` as in the snippet from [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/text-io#reading-from-compressed-text-files):

```
Pipeline p = ...;
p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadMyFile")
                   .from("gs://some/inputData.gz")
                   .withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP));
```

Take into account that, if you don't specify the compression type, it will default to `AUTO` type and infer it's a gzipped file due to the `.gz` extension.

However, this seems to be now [deprecated](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/) and the docs recommend to use [`Compression`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/Compression.html) instead. An example in Beam's [repo](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/CompressedSource.java#L38):

```
FileBasedSource<T> mySource = ...;
PCollection<T> collection = p.apply(Read.from(CompressedSource
    .from(mySource)
    .withCompression(Compression.GZIP)));
```